# status 404 with angular.js, but reachable via browser

Tags: angularjs, web.py

I am running a simple web.py LAN server on port 8089 which returns "hello" for any request:

```
class predict:
    def GET(self):
        web.header('Content-Type','text/plain')
        return 'hello'
```

It is working fine when I access it via a browser. However, when I try to use angular.js, it keeps giving 404s. Firebug doesn't report any problems. Here is the HTML and angular code (which are in a local .html file):

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
<p>
<input placeholder="Type a word" type="text" ng-model="title"/><br/><br/>
Result = {{result}}
</p>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function TestCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.$watch('title', function (new_value) {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://10.33.133.166:8089/predict'}).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope.result = data;
                    }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope.result = status;
                    });
    });
}
</script>
```

Any ideas why the behavior might be different in angular and browser?

Comment: `Accept` header from Angular will be `application/json`.

Comment: The issue could be also due to cross domain querying.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that cross-domain querying was the cause. I put the html file on the same server and everything is working fine now!